# How to call a directive from a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using DOM manipulation in a controller which I know it is not correct!

But, I need to know how to create a directive and then call it from a controller

here is the controller where I am doing the DOM manipulation

```
$scope.myPopover = $popover(angular.element('#betConf'), { //<--
  title: 'Bet Confirmation',
  template: 'views/betConfirmModal.html',
  html: true,
  autoClose: true,
  placement: 'bottom',
  trigger: 'manual',
  animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
  scope: $scope
});
```

and I am calling it this way

```
$scope.myPopover.show();
```

so, what should I do to make a directive, then call it in that controller without putting the directive directly in the DOM ?

**EDIT TO EXPLAIN BETTER**

the function `$scope.myPopover` is in the same controller I am calling `$scope.myPopover.show();`,

```
$scope.placeStraightBet = function(slip) {
  $scope.betId = '';
  var winValue = parseFloat(slip.risk, 10),
    riskValue = parseFloat(slip.win, 10),
    riskWin;
  // HERE CALL THE DIRECTIVE
  $scope.myPopover.show();
}
```

all I need is to create a directive, and call it in this controller, something like:

```
$scope.placeStraightBet = function(slip) {
  $scope.betId = '';
  var winValue = parseFloat(slip.risk, 10),
    riskValue = parseFloat(slip.win, 10),
    riskWin;
  // HERE CALL THE DIRECTIVE
  myDirective();
}
```

or:

```
$scope.myPopover = $popover(myElementDirective, {
  title: 'Bet Confirmation',
  template: 'views/betConfirmModal.html',
  html: true,
  autoClose: true,
  placement: 'bottom',
  trigger: 'manual',
  animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
  scope: $scope
});
```

all I want is avoid the usage of the DOM in the controller.

Comment: why don't use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ angular ui bootstrap

Comment: It looks like your code defines a $scope variable called myPopover not an actual AngularJS Controller. I suggest you rephrase this question because it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can put an ng-if on a directive usually and put it in the template, just a thought.

Comment: @pankajparkar I am about to get done with this project. I can not switch just like that.

Comment: @JackShultz look at my **EDIT** part

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer I'm having a little trouble understanding the concept of calling a directive from controller, I don't think I can give you any advise on that because it does not seem like that is the way angular works. If you could tell me what your directive is supposed to do I might be able to give some better advise. As I understand, directives are referenced in your template and can revise the html. You could add a directive programmatically to the html and compile it again. But calling a directive from a controller I don' follow that.

Comment: @JackShultz I need to avoid the usage of the DOM manipulation in the controller, that's it, so ```$scope.myPopover = $popover(myElementDirective, {...})``` instead of ```$scope.myPopover = $popover(angular.element('#betConf'), {})``` got it ?

Comment: So why not assign the directive to your html template?

Comment: the main usage of that directive, is possibly to wrap the element, and then shoot that element to the controller, in order to avoid the DOM manip... @JackShultz

Comment: @JackShultz, OK, teach me how

Comment: Here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller and I guess also https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers since one of the latter two is what it sounds like you actually want

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer: Where do you call `$scope.myPopover.show()` in view? How you put the controller in your view? Because directive is called in views not controller itself

Answer (score 1):

You could create a directive with a "show" attribute, and set a watcher for when this property changes, like this:

```
angular.module('yourAppName')
  .directive('myPopover', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        show: '=',
      },
      link: function postLink($scope, element) {

        $scope.$watch('show', function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if(newVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
              $popover(element, { 
                 title: 'Bet Confirmation',
                 template: 'views/betConfirmModal.html',
                 html: true,
                 autoClose: true,
                 placement: 'bottom',
                 trigger: 'manual',
                 animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
                 scope: $scope.$parent
              }).show();

          }
        });            
      }
    };
  });
```

Your view would look something like this:

```
<my-popover show="showPopover"></my-popover>
```

And from your controller you show it by setting $scope.showPopover to true:

```
$scope.placeStraightBet = function(slip) {
  $scope.betId = '';
  var winValue = parseFloat(slip.risk, 10),
    riskValue = parseFloat(slip.win, 10),
    riskWin;
  // HERE CALL THE DIRECTIVE
  $scope.showPopover = true;
}
```

Comment: this is a good solution but I am getting this: ```TypeError: tipLinker is not a function``` here the docs for what I am using http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers

Comment: is tipLinker part of your controller's scope?

Comment: nope, it is something of the Angular Strap library.

Comment: I couldn't find it in the docs, but try setting the scope to $scope.$parent (see updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

Taking some of the answer of Jack Shultz, 
Creating a directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('bululu').directive('movement', function( $timeout, $interval) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope : {},
    link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
      scope.elementsArray = ['facebook', 'linkedin', 'twitter', 'googleplus', 'mail', 'pinterest', 'behance', 'wordpress'];


      scope.moveElements = function() {
        $timeout(function(){
          for (var i = 0; i < scope.elementsArray.length; i++ ) {
            var top = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 100 ) + 1 );
            var left = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 100 ) + 1 );
            var target = document.getElementById(scope.elementsArray[i]);
            scope.element = angular.element(target);
            scope.element.css({
              'top': top + '%',
              'left': left + '%'
            });
          }
        }, 1000);
      };

      scope.moveElements();

      $interval( function() {
        scope.moveElements();
      }, 6000);

    },
 };
```

});

The restrict value defines how to "call" a directive, as stated in the Directive Documentation:
The restrict option is typically set to:

'A' - only matches attribute name

```
<div movement></div>
```

'E' - only matches element name

```
<movement></movement>
```

'C' - only matches class name

```
<div class="movement"></div>
```

If you create an isolated scope, then every DOM element inside the directive div will use the scope.

```
<div movement>
    <button>Click here</button>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Setting the scope attribute of the directive as false will share the scope with the controller, functions and variables could be shared this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what directive might look like

```
angular.module('app.module', [])
.directive('myElementDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    title: 'Bet Confirmation',
    template: 'views/betConfirmModal.html',
    html: true,
    autoClose: true,
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'manual',
    animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
    scope: $scope
  };
});
```

Then in your html template you can assign this directive as an attribute

```
<div my-element-directive></div>
```

Comment: that's what I don't get, where to put ```my-element-directive``` ? I mean, that is for a popover, and all I have in the DOM is the id ```betConf```

Comment: The directive will inject the betConfirmModal.html wherever in the DOM you put it so long has it is part of your ng-app context. So if you put ng-app directive in the html tag you could put your directive after the </body> which might be how you would handle a popup. But there is actually an angular dialog directive you might consider using https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog